# how to read values from custom class

Tags: objective-c

I have class Person.

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *screen_name;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *screen_name;

@end
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

@synthesize text,screen_name;

@end
```

I have NSArray object, with values, such as text, screen_name and etc.

I do:

```
Person * person = object; ( object is NSArray)
```

I would like get values, like this:
person.**name**, person.**screen_name**

**object** :

```
{
        "screen_name" = "mika_alcala";
        "text" ="";
        "time_zone" = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)";
        "url" = "<null>";
        "utc_offset" = "-14400";
        "verified" = 0;
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. `object` is an `NSArray`, I understand this. What are you trying to do with it? Can you perhaps show the contents of `object` and maybe explain what you want to do? What is the code `Person *person = object;` trying to do? It looks like you're trying to create a `Person` from the array?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm trying to create Person from array.

Comment: OK, can you show the contents of the NSArray (i.e. `NSLog(@"%@", object);`) paste the result of this in to your question.

Comment: OK, will edit my answer...

Answer (score 1):

OK, first you don't need to define the ivars and you don't need the synthesize with XCode 4.5+ (IIRC).

So it should look like...

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *screen_name;

@end
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

@end
```

For the actual question I'm not sure what you're asking. I'll have to ask further...

**EDIT to show how to create from array**

First off...

```
object :
{
        "screen_name" = "mika_alcala";
        "text" ="";
        "time_zone" = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)";
        "url" = "<null>";
        "utc_offset" = "-14400";
        "verified" = 0;
};
```

This object is actually an `NSDictionary` not and `NSArray`.

There are two ways of doing this...

1. Create a blank `Person` object and then set the values from the dictionary.

   ```
   Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
   person.name = object[@"screen_name"];
   person.screen_name = object[@"screen_name"];
   ```
2. Add a custom init method to the `Person` object.

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *screen_name;

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

@end
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = dictionary[@"screen_name"];
        _screen_name = dictionary[@"screen_name"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then you can just do...

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithDictionary:object];
```

Whichever method you follow you will then be able to get hold of `person.name` and `person.screen_name`.

Comment: After I allocated person variable, I want to get name by call : person.text or person.screen_name